# Automapper - map collection containing 'null' and initialized objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following situation. I am mapping a list of a class to a list of an identical class within another namespace. In the original list, some objects may be null, some may be correctly initialized.
When mapping, I receive an AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException for this list.
Whenever I populate the list with objects which are all null or objects which were all initialized, the mapping works fine.

Example program I used to reproduce this problem:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;
using AutomapperTest.Namespace1;

namespace AutomapperTest.Namespace1
{
    public class Identifier
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace AutomapperTest.Namespace2
{
    public class Identifier
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace AutomapperTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Identifier, Namespace2.Identifier>();
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            var identifierList = new List<Identifier>
                {
                    null,
                    new Identifier()
                };

            var mappedList = Mapper.Map<List<Namespace2.Identifier>>(identifierList);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a solution to make this mapping succeed? I'm expecting a list containing 2 Namespace2.Identifier objects, of which one of them is null, identically to the source collection.

Comment: Code you provided does not reproduce problem - it returns two objects - null and instance of Namespace2.Identifier

Comment: @BartoszKP there is no problem now - currently AutoMapper maps nulls without any additional settings

Comment: @BartoszKP you can add comment to that question/answer that AllowNullDestinationValues is set to true by default :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I forgot to mention I was using Automapper V2.1.267. The latest release version (3.1.1) indeed works as expected.
Thanks!